# Create Page object in Java Class using URL

Tags: aem

In my Java class in an OSGi bundle, I have the URI of a page -

```
String pageUri = "/content/site/page.html" ;
```

How can I create a Page object using this URL ? I basically need to fetch the page properties also from the object later on...

I tried this code in my class:

```
PageManager pm = new PageManager();
Page page = pm.getPage(pageUri);
```

But this gives me compilation error:

```
Cannot instantiate the type PageManager
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to inject a ResourceResolverFactory instance into your component/service and from there resolve the Resource/Page as described in [Getting Resources and Properties in Sling](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/getting-resources-and-properties-in-sling.html#within-an-osgi-servicecompoment).

For example:

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service(GetMeAPage.class)
public class GetMeAPage {

    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resourceResolverFactory;

    private static final String pageUri = "/content/site/page.html";

    /**
     * This method is executed at component startup rather than in the context of a request.
     */
    @Activate
    public void getSpecificPage() {
        ResourceResolver resourceResolver = null;
        try {
            resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
            Page page = getSpecificPage(resourceResolver);
            System.out.println(page.getTitle());
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resourceResolver != null) {
                resourceResolver.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public Page getSpecificPage(ResourceResolver resourceResolver) {
        Resource resource = resourceResolver.resolve(pageUri);
        return resource.adaptTo(Page.class);

    }
}
```

[Full code in this gist](https://gist.github.com/cpilsworth/6375518)

This uses an *administrative login* which is [not ideal](http://www.pro-vision.de/content/medialib/pro-vision/production/adaptto/2012/adaptto2012-security-issues-with-loginadministrative-angela-schr/_jcr_content/renditions/rendition.file/adaptto2012-security-issues-with-loginadministrative-angela-schreiber.pdf).  I would recommend using the ResourceResolver from the request.  The simplest way of doing this is to pass it as a method parameter to `getSpecificPage(resourceResolver)` (above) from your component/servlet.

**Update:**
The correct way of doing this in more recent versions of Sling (circa 2014, AEM6+) is to use [Sling Service Authentication](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/service-authentication.html).  The getAdministrativeResourceResolver method is now deprecated.

Comment: I wanted to know how to get the Page object for the path selected from the pathfield dialog and then list the child pages for the selected path. Could anyone help?

Comment: @manojpt It might be worth raising a separate question for this

Answer (score 2):

If by a "class within an OSGi bundle", you're extending the **SlingAllMethodsServlet**, you'll have access to the request, from which you can get the resolver/page manager.

```
class Foo extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, 
                         SlingHttpServletResponse response) 
        throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {

           ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
           PageManager pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);

           String pageUri = "/content/site/page.html" ;
           Page page = pageManager.getPage(pageUri);
    }
}
```

It depends on what your set-up is within this bundle.

Comment: My class actually is implementing "TransformerFactory " . It is ti be sued a s aLink writer and I don't seem to have an SlingHttpServletRequest  in hand. :(

Comment: Then as @diffa mentioned above, you can annotate a `@Reference` to the ResourceResolver factory & get it that way.

Answer (score 1):

PageManager can not be instantiated. To get an instance you can adapt a resource resolver:
resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class).

The resourceResolver can normally be obtained from the resource:
resource.getResourceResolver(), you can also obtain it directly from a sling request

Comment: Yeah.. I get the point.. but then how can I instantiate the Resource Resolver ?  Apparently, ResourceResolver resolver = new ResourceResolver(); doesn't work !

Comment: @RijuMahna In Sling/CQ5 and OSGi in general you never instantiate service objects. Services like factories are injected to components  (as in diffa's answer), or adapt them from other objects using adaptTo(). The resourceResolver can be adapter not only to PageManager but also Session or a QueryBuilder